# Mysql select for update blocks 1st insert if using NON primary key in where clause

Tags: mysql, locking, primary-key, innodb

Mysql Version : 5.6.33 , ubuntu 64 bit

**Table Schema**

```
CREATE TABLE `zone_txn` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `bucket_key` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `idx_bucket_key` (`bucket_key`)
)
```

2 sessions are opened and race condition is induced by running 1 statement from each terminal. Statement numbers are mentioned.

**Terminal 1**

```
S1: begin;
S3:     select * from zone_txn FORCE INDEX(idx_bucket_key)
            WHERE `bucket_key` = 'b1' FOR UPDATE;
S5:     insert into zone_txn(`bucket_key`) values('b1');
S7: commit;
```

**Terminal 2**

```
S2: begin;
S4:     select * from zone_txn FORCE INDEX(idx_bucket_key)
           WHERE `bucket_key` = 'b2' FOR UPDATE;
S6:     insert into zone_txn(`bucket_key`) values('b2');
S8: commit;
```

According to [doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locking-reads.html) , select for update "only locks the rows it has passed through just like update".

**Question :** 
Insert query is blocked in the whichever session receives the first insert query. 
Insert query after this blocked query ( in second session ) works fine.
In above example S5 blocks, S6 runs fine.

Is it dues to gap lock or next-key lock as specified [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locking.html) where fresh insert is being blocked by Index.

If I put `id` = <> in where clause , then both insert queries run fine.

**Terminal 1**

```
S1: begin;
S3:     select * from zone_txn WHERE `id` = 1 FOR UPDATE;
S5:     insert into zone_txn(`bucket_key`) values('b1');
S7: commit;
```

**Terminal 2**

```
S2: begin;
S4:     select * from zone_txn WHERE `id` = 2 FOR UPDATE;
S6:     insert into zone_txn(`bucket_key`) values('b2');
S8: commit;
```

UPDATED:
If I make bucket_key as unique index , it works fine. Looks like it only works for unique and Primary keys and not ranges.

UPDATED : Fixed Typo, added "for update" in select statements which were part of the question.

UPDATED : Starting value of zone_txn;

```
+----+------------+
| id | bucket_key |
+----+------------+
|  1 | b1         |
|  2 | b2         |
+----+------------+
```

show engine innodb status;

```
---TRANSACTION 1139415, ACTIVE 11 sec
4 lock struct(s), heap size 1184, 4 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 8818, OS thread handle 0x700009268000, query id 1700769 localhost root cleaning up

---TRANSACTION 1139414, ACTIVE 16 sec inserting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 5 lock struct(s), heap size 1184, 4 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 8626, OS thread handle 0x7000092f0000, query id 1700768 localhost root update
insert into zone_txn(`bucket_key`) values('b1')

------- TRX HAS BEEN WAITING 6 SEC FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 1454 page no 4 n bits 72 index `idx_bucket_key` of table `kyc`.`zone_txn` trx id 1139414 lock_mode X locks gap before rec insert intention waiting
Record lock, heap no 3 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 2; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 2; hex 6232; asc b2;;
 1: len 8; hex 8000000000000002; asc         ;;
```

Comment: Please provide `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;` at the appropriate time.  Are "b1" and "b2" adjacent values in the index?  Was there any "gap" locking?

Comment: @RickJames : I have pasted the txn part of show engine innodb status. Kindly check.

Comment: "If I put id = <> in where clause..." -- I don't understand.

Comment: If the table started with the rows you are are about to insert, do you actually run the `INSERTs` had have them fail?  Or is some code missing from the transactions you are showing?

Comment: @RickJames "If I run id = <>" : select * from zone_txn WHERE `id` = 1 FOR UPDATE and similarly `id` = 2 in 2nd session  ( updated question ) ...

Comment: @RickJames : To simulate the case, I inserted 2 rows before I conducted the test.

Comment: (1) Try it with a value between b1 and b2.  Or (2) with an id between 1 and 2.  Or (3) with `UNIQUE(bucket_key)`.  I am thinking that, since `bucket_key` is not `UNIQUE`, the S3 will actually touch _two_ rows -- that is, until it finds a row without `b1`.  In which case, (1) and (3) not block.  (I don't know about (2).)